# Как создать нужный инстанс класса по имени без switch?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Пользователь вводит имя фигуры и нужно создать класс этой фигуры. То есть какой класс создавать определяется в *runtime*. Как это можно сделать без `switch`?

Comment: (1) много ифов (2) замапить

Answer (score 2):

Если речь именно про Qt, то можно воспользоваться местным рефлекшном - должен помочь класс `QMetaType`:

```
int typeId = QMetaType::type("MyClass");

if (typeId != QMetaType::UnknownType) {
    void *myClassPtr = QMetaType::create(typeId);
    ...
    QMetaType::destroy(typeId, myClassPtr);
    myClassPtr = 0;
    ...
}
```

Тип `MyClass`, разумеется, нужно предварительно зарегистрировать. Подробности - [в документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details).

Comment: Зачем обнуление указателя перед выходом из блока?

Comment: @alexolut, копипаста фрагмента из документации же) полагаю затем, чтобы в реальном коде (когда после деструкции идут другие операторы) при попытке в него что-то записать  программа просто скрашилась, вместо длительной и печальной отладки внезапных спец.эффектов.

Comment: Вижу теперь, что копипаста, но других операторов же нет в примере. Можно, конечно, предположить, что в первом вашем троеточии указатель куда-то наружу передаётся по ссылке/указателю, но это ещё более ужасная ситуация :)